# Bold a part of title, iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read several method about bolding a part of string.
But I still can't get it work.

Here's my code

```
#define FONT_OPEN_BOLD(s) [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:s]
```

In viewDidLoad function

```
NSString *stringName = @"ShowTimes" ;                     
UIFont *font = FONT_OPEN_BOLD(15.0f);
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringName];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

self.title = stringName;
```

Any suggestion? 
Thank you in advance. ^^

Comment: What is `self`? A view controller, bar button item, something else?

Comment: It is tabBarItem sir.

Comment: `UITabBarItem` doesn't support titles with attributed text.

Comment: how can i solve this issue?
Or I should have UILabel be my title?
Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: Wait, if this code is in a view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, how can `self` be a `UITabBarItem`?

Comment: Sorry rmaddy, I have wrong understanding.
It's a viewController T__T

Comment: Then what is title since viewcontroller dosnt have a title object

Comment: @m-farhan Of course `UIViewController` has a `title` property. Why do you say it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *stringName = @"ShowTimes" ;                     
UIFont *font = FONT_OPEN_BOLD(15.0f);
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringName];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

//Initialize TTAttributedLabel with rect
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 150)];
//Set the attributedText property of TTAttributedLabel
label.attributedText = attrString;
//Set navigationItem.titleView to the label view we've created
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Comment: What is `self`? And since `title` is clearly an `NSString`, there is no `attributedText` property to set.

Comment: My understanding is title is uilable

Comment: @AdamEberbach How can `title` be a `UILabel`. The OP clearly assigned it an `NSString`. If it was a `UILabel` it would need to be `self.title.text = someString;`.

Comment: @m-farhan As you can see in the comments above, `self` is a `UITabBarItem`. Your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not going to work unless it is a UILabel, which has an attributedText attribute.

Comment: So now that we know that `self` is really a `UIViewController`, this answer is appropriate. Though I would suggest making the answer a bit more complete. Show how the label is created.

Comment: My macbook stucked in black screen T__T. Sorry for slow replyings.
I will try to use UILabel.
And I will report you the result soon.
Thank you all very much =D

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for telling me that viewcontroller has title object i dont know how come i missed it in last 4 years thanks though

Comment: Why are you posting an answer with `TTTAttributedLabel`? Just use `UILabel`. It's supported attribute text since iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use an NSAttributedString.

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = ...;
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
```

//draw attrString here...
Take a look at [this handy dandy guide](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) to drawing NSAttributedString objects with Core Text.